# Python global variables in shared modules

Tags: python, global

I am trying to understand the behavior of variables shared across modules.  My impression was a global variable in one module could be accessed in another, and sometimes this seems to be what happens, but sometimes it is not.  (I recognize global variables are usually not the right tool, but there are situations where their use is appropriate.)

Here is a code example to illustrate my confusion:

shared.py

```
globalvar=0                 # a global scalar variable
globalarray1=[1,2,3]        # a global array modified by .append()
globalarray2=['A','B','C']  # a global array modified by reassignment

def set_globals():
    global globalvar
    global globalarray1
    global globalarray2

    globalvar=1
    globalarray1.append(4)
    globalarray2=['a','b','c']

    print("set_globals: globalvar="+str(globalvar))
    print("set_globals: globalarray1="+str(globalarray1))
    print("set_globals: globalarray2="+str(globalarray2))
```

module.py

```
from paas.shared import *

def _main_():
    global globalvar
    global globalarray1
    global globalarray2

    set_globals()

    print("main: globalvar="+str(globalvar))
    print("main: globalarray1="+str(globalarray1))
    print("main: globalarray2="+str(globalarray2))

_main_()
```

When I run the program, I get the following output:

```
set_globals: globalvar=1
set_globals: globalarray1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
set_globals: globalarray2=['a', 'b', 'c']
main: globalvar=0
main: globalarray1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
main: globalarray2=['A', 'B', 'C']
```

So

- 'main' is not seeing the same scalar variable 'globalvar' that is being set by the 'set_globals' method in the shared module (the assignment 'took' and was printed within 'set_globals' but 'main' is printing something else.
- It does appear to be seeing the same 'globalarray1' - the append(4) that modified globalarray1 in set_globals is recognized when it is printed by 'main'.
- It is not seeing the same 'globalarray2' - the variable assigned in set_globals is correctly printed by 'set_globals', but 'main' is printing the original value assigned to globalarray2.

Can someone explain what is going on?  I have only seen fairly simple tutorial-type documentation about global variables; if there is documentation that describes what is happening here I would appreciate a pointer.

ADDED NOTE: This is not related to the way a local variable in a function hides a global variable with the same name; those are two different variables with the same name and different initial values.  It does appear that the import creates a new module variable with the same name, but it starts with the initial value of the variable of the same name from the imported module.

Comment: When you do `from module import var`, it copies the current value of `var` from module `module` into the current namespace.  If the module then assigns to that variable in its namespace, they will no longer refer to the same object.  But if it merely modifies the object it references (such as appending to a list), then they will continue to refer to the same object.  This is exactly how it behaves if you assign one variable to another locally.  E.g. `x = 5; y = x; x = 6` vs. `x = [1, 2, 3]; y = x; x.append(4)`.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether that dupe actually does describe the behaviour here even though it mentions variables across modules

Comment: @TomKarzes that seems like what I am suspecting: both modules have a 'local' variable pointing to, initially, the same object, but the assignments seem to change the variable in that module only to point to a new object.  When the object is modified destructively everybody pointing to that object sees the change.That is different from how a local variable in a function hides a global variable.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the globals-in-function question.  The first answer below is working, is appropriate, and very different from what is going on in the "globals-in-function" question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're observing stems from Python's behavior with respect to variables, imports, and mutability. Let's break it down:

1. Shared Mutable Objects (Lists in this case):

- `globalarray1` is a list, which is a mutable object in Python. When you do `globalarray1.append(4)`, you are mutating the original list object.
- When you import `globalarray1` in `module.py` using `from paas.shared import *`, you are importing a reference to that list object. Therefore, when you mutate the list in `shared.py`, that mutation is visible in module.py.

2. Reassigning Variables:

- `globalarray2=['a','b','c']` inside `set_globals` reassigns the variable to a new list object. However, `module.py` still references the original list object.
- For the scalar `globalvar`, when you set `globalvar=1` inside `set_globals`, you're modifying the value of the variable within the scope of `shared.py`. However, in `module.py`, the `globalvar` still references the old value (0).

3. Python's Import Mechanism:

- When you use the syntax `from paas.shared import *`, you're importing the names from `shared.py` into `module.py`. If you later rebind one of these names in `shared.py` (as you do with `globalvar` and `globalarray2`), the binding in `module.py` remains unchanged.

How to fix this and see consistent behavior:

You should access variables from the shared module using an explicit module prefix. This way, you're always referring to the most recent value of the variable in the shared module. Here's how you can change your `module.py`, let's call it `module2.py`:

```
import paas.shared as shared

def _main_():
    shared.set_globals()

    print("main: globalvar="+str(shared.globalvar))
    print("main: globalarray1="+str(shared.globalarray1))
    print("main: globalarray2="+str(shared.globalarray2))

_main_()
```

With this change, the print statements in `_main_()` will refer directly to the shared module's versions of the variables, and you'll see consistent behavior between `set_globals` and `_main_()`.

Now let's compare the output. Here's `module.py` (unmodified from above):

```
$ python module.py

   set_globals: globalvar=1
   set_globals: globalarray1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
   set_globals: globalarray2=['a', 'b', 'c']
   main: globalvar=0
   main: globalarray1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
   main: globalarray2=['A', 'B', 'C']
```

And now the new code using an explicit import (`module2.py`):

```
$ python module2.py  
                        
   set_globals: globalvar=1
   set_globals: globalarray1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
   set_globals: globalarray2=['a', 'b', 'c']
   main: globalvar=1
   main: globalarray1=[1, 2, 3, 4]
   main: globalarray2=['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy

Comment: This does seem to describe what I am seeing.  I will explore using a handle on the import statement; if that works _I_ think this is a pretty complete answer.

Comment: What's the output you're seeing when running the modified module.py?

Comment: This is working.